# Cannot import python-bitcoinrpc

Tags: json-rpc, python

I am unable to import the package `bitcoinrpc`.

I have installed it in python2 and python3 using `python3 -m pip install python-bitcoinrpc`/`python -m pip install python-bitcoinrpc` AND by cloning the repo and editing the python environment in `setup.py` to my python2 and 3 path. Which returns `Requirement already satisfied: python-bitcoinrpc in /home/a/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (1.0)`

Even after that I get the following errors:

Python2: `ImportError: No module named authproxy`

Python3: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bitcoinrpc.authproxy'; 'bitcoinrpc' is not a package`

Following is my code:

```
from bitcoinrpc.authproxy import AuthServiceProxy, JSONRPCException

# rpc_user and rpc_password are set in the bitcoin.conf file
rpc_user = "xxx"
rpc_password = "xxx"
rpc_connection = AuthServiceProxy("http://%s:%s@127.0.0.1:8332"%(rpc_user, rpc_password))

print(rpc_connection.get_info())
```

I have searched as much as I could but, cannot find anyting except for [this bitcoin stackexchange question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/85333/python-bitcoinrpc-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-bitcoinrpc) without an answer.

ENV: OS: Mint 19.1 with Anaconda where `which python(3)` return `/usr/bin/python(3)`

Is the setup broken or am I missing something?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had named my script `bitcoinrpc.py` and had the import `bitcoinrpc`. Naturally it couldn't find the `package`. Renamed the script and it works.

Lesson: DO NOT have a file of the same name as the package you are trying to import.